# Iptables filtering performance: TCP and UDP

Tags: tcp, udp, iptables, throughput

i am writting to ask about iptables performance in TCP and UDP filtering. I was testing it with large number of iptables rules.
When in FORWARD chain is 10 000 mixed TCP and UDP rules i get TCP throughput 35.5 Mbits/sec and UDP  throughput 25.2 Mbits/sec

I am confused why TCP throughput is bigger than UDP? I thought TCP will be slower because of ACK packets. I have already tested it with cisco ACL, there UDP is faster.

PC ---- FW ----- PC
Topology

Answer (score 1):

Firewall overhead is most significant with respect to packets, not bytes.  So if the average UDP packets were smaller than the average TCP packets, then the CPU will be maxed out at a smaller number of bits-per-second with UDP than with TCP.

Conversely, if the UDP packets are large enough to cause fragmentation and the firewall is configured to reassemble fragments before inspecting them, then the reassembly will cause substantial overhead which will reduce bits-per-second throughput.

There may be also other factors specific to the firewall implementation and configuration, but I believe those two would be first-order.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I captured outgoing packets with wireshark. And i discover that TCP packet lenght is huge.

Comment: Wireshark has an option for TCP packet reassembly, which concatenates multiple packets into segment.  So those sizes may not represent the actual IP-level datagram size.  See if you can turn reassembly off to get a more "raw" view of the network.  If you really do have TCP packets that are nearly 3000 bytes long, then something is very wrong as standard TCP will not go over 1500 MTU without some kind of configuration telling it to do so.